# Create a URL like "teach.joshhornby.co.uk"

Tags: apache, url, hosting, virtualhost

I am trying to create a URL on my server such as the one above `teach.joshhornby.co.uk`

When people type in the address I want them to access a folder on my server called backend.

I have tried this in my virtual host in the http.d file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/backend
ServerName www.teach.joshhornby.co.uk

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Nothing happens when I enter this URL in a browser. I own joshhornby.co.uk so in theory should be able to create a sub domain.

Comment: What about `www.` part? And I think this Q belongs to serverfault and not to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a couple more directives for the directory eg:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/backend
ServerName www.teach.joshhornby.co.uk
<Directory /var/www/html/backend>
Allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Otherwise, have you created a DNS entry for the subdomain? from the command line, can you ping www.teach.joshhornby.co.uk? if not the browser won't know which IP to use for www.teach.joshhorny.co.uk.
You can sort this out at your domain registrar, add an A record for teach.joshhornby.co.uk and for www.teach.joshhorny.co.uk with the value set to the IP of your server.

Comment: Almost there, the domain is now pointing to the root of my site but not to the correct folder. I have checked the path and it seems correct. file:///var/www/html/backend this is what I get back when I look at the path.